# Xcopy complete operation successfully, but the copy does not occur

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, batch-processing, xcopy

i'm having a weird problem about copying with Xcopy.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2. There is a Batch file (.CMD) - in fact, 2 Batches - which executes many operations. Among them there are 2 Xcopy.

The first Xcopy completes the copy successfully. Then some operations of batch are executed and...the second Xcopy is executed after some time. It shows a successfully status, like "300 files copied" but...the files are not copied !

THE strange behaviour: i put a pause command into the Batch and, after this second weird Xcopy, i run THE SAME command at the Prompt and..it works !!!

I cannot explain this, so i'm asking for help here. The full command is:

`xcopy /s /e /h /r /i /y E: D:`

As a matter of curiosity/information, the other Xcopy (which worked!) is:

`xcopy /s /e /h /r /i /y E: D:`

Or....**the same command** !!! Each one runs in a separated Batch file - the first Batch "calls" the second one.

E: is CD-ROM, so after the first Xcopy, the first Batch asks for another Disc and calls the second Batch, which (supposed) copies entire CD content to D: (HDD).

I'm sorry if the question is silly and i'm not realizing how simple is to correct the erratic behaviour of Xcopy. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much Bali C !

But i found the problem: the correct syntax is

`xcopy /s /e /h /r /i /y E:\ D:\`

You can see that the backslashes made all the difference ! The files were being copied to another directory, in fact, the current working directory. With backslashes the copy is fine.

But i appreciate your suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

To copy the entire contents try using

`xcopy /e /h /r /i /y /t E:\*.* D:\`

I left out the `/s` as it contradicts the `/e` switch, I doubt it will be the source of the problem but it's worth a shot. I used the `\t` switch to copy the directory structure of the source.

I have also used wildcards `*.*` to copy the contents, rather than just the drive letter, some things work at cmd prompt but not in batch, but try using this.

Another option would be to use `robocopy`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the documentation of xcopy states that /e should be used in conjunction with /s or /t.  Source: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true